# Why does MFC want me to set a registry key?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, registrykey

When I created my MFC C++ application in Visual Studio 2010, the following lines of code were placed in my main source file inside `InitInstance()`:

```
// TODO: You should modify this string to be something appropriate
// such as the name of your company or organization
SetRegistryKey(_T(""));
```

It says that I should modify the string to something appropriate, however I don't think I ever use a Registry Key.  What is the point of using SetRegistryKey and will the string ever be seen by the user of my program?  Should I just delete this block of code?

Comment: Yes, delete it.  That's the only way to be sure that you are not in fact using MFC functions that use the registry.  You'll get an assert if you guessed wrong.

Comment: Your concern is misplaced.  Plenty of applications write data to the registry to persist states and values.  There shouldn't be any risk as long as you don't expose information that should not be exposed.

Comment: I would recommend that you just comment it out, rather than delete it.  While at the moment you may not think you need to utilize the registry, if you ever need to use it, the framework will still be there in comment form.  I would actually "comment out" all 3 lines (including the TODO comment lines) so that you can "uncomment out" all 3 related lines at a later date (VS IDE makes both of these editing operations very easy to do with a single mouse click).

Comment: I believe recent iterations of MFC use the registry (at least by default) to persist things like the application look, and sizes/positions of docking windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a boilerplate code, to be adjusted if you use registry to read/write application data.

If you don't use registry, this line can be deleted.

See [CWinApp::SetRegistryKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c2w6z4k.aspx):

> Causes application settings to be stored in the registry instead of INI files.
>
> ....
>
> This function sets *m_pszRegistryKey*, which is then used by the **GetProfileInt**, **GetProfileString**, **WriteProfileInt**, and **WriteProfileString** member functions of **CWinApp**. If this function has been called, the list of most recently-used (MRU) files is also stored in the registry. The registry key is usually the name of a company. It is stored in a key of the following form: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\<company name>\<application name>\<section name>\<value name>`.